# Will having a "mr" in the given name of my ticket cause any problems?

Tags: tickets

On my passport Given name is Castiel  and last name is Black.

On the ticket my given name is `Castielmr` and the title field is blank.
So it is printed as `Castielmr Black`

I cant remove the mr now from the booking website of qatar airline. My travel agent did the booking.

Answer (score 1):

No this is perfectly normal.

It will not cause you any problems.

Most travel agents and airlines outside of North America will add the appropriate title to the end of the given name field.

There is no title field on airline tickets, whether they are paper tickets or etickets. That seems to have been an oversight by the original designer of the airline paper ticket. It is a universal system that all major airlines use, so in countries where the title is an important part of the name, it just has to go at the end.